# Httponly cookies do not work in Android Chrome

Tags: android, .net, google-chrome, cookies, jwt

I have a .NET Core Web API that uses JWR in cookies for authentication. Everything is OK, however in Android Chrome httponly cookies are missing. I tested in Android Firefox and everything was OK. So, I have this problem only on Android Chrome.

This is how I set my cookies:

```
  var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
  {
      Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(6),
      HttpOnly = true,
      Secure = options.Secure,
      SameSite = (SameSiteMode)options.SameSite,
      Domain = options.Domain,
  };

  var authCookieOptions = new CookieOptions
  {
      Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(6),
      HttpOnly = false,
      Secure = options.Secure,
      SameSite = (SameSiteMode)options.SameSite,
      Domain = options.Domain,
  };

  var httpContext = accessor?.HttpContext;

  httpContext?.Response.Cookies.Append(CookieName.AccessToken, token, cookieOptions);
  httpContext?.Response.Cookies.Append(CookieName.Auth, username, authCookieOptions);
```

I tried changing `SameSite` and `Domain` but it didn't help. Any advice would be appreciated.